# Freeform pro - Error in Dynamic Recipients

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I am having a problem with Freeform PRO - when I create dynamic recipient select lists using composer they are not rendering correctly, here is an example output:

```
<div class="unit size1of2">
    <label class="field_label">Venue</label>
        <p>
        <select name="recipient_email"></select>
        <option value="0">--</option>

        <option value="5359413bda2ea9.89526262">Sandinista Manchester</option>
        <option value="5359413bda3007.33768703">test</option>

    </p>
</div>
```

So you can see the select list is not wrapping round the options, so it doesnt render correctly on the page.

Feels like a bug in Freeform. Can anyone from Solspace help please?

Thanks,
Martyn

Comment: What version of Freeform and EE are you using?

Comment: I'm also having trouble reproducing this issue on my side. Are you using a custom Composer Template?

Comment: Hi Solspace, it is EE v2.7.3 and Freeform 4.1.7. It is just the standard Composer Template. Thanks!

Comment: Had another look at the code, it is producing this error when we pull in a form through ajax. We have a series of buttons that when clicked run an ajax get function to retrieve a form contained in page template. All the other non dynamic select dropdowns work fine, so perhaps this is related to the parsing of the data within the dynamic select list?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the page template URL containing your form directly, i.e. not loading with ajax? Is the select field well-formatted then? You might have to open a support ticket on support.solspace.com for this one. Please provide CP and FTP creds if possible.